# What's the best available online resource for Windows Mobile Development?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

What's the best available online resource.

Answer (score 2):

I have only played with the Mobile Framework briefly but a good start would be [Windows Mobile Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx)

Also it is worth looking at some example open source projects on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=windows%20mobile). 
Microsoft on every training event is encouraging people to use it, and from my experience you can find some interesting projects there at least in standard .Net. I suppose the same applies to Mobile

Answer (score 2):

[Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/) has a few tutorials on Windows Mobile Device. Most of them are quite involved, spread over multiple posts, and covers different aspects of Windows Mobile development. As the name implies most applications are about small games and hacks rather than anything you could use in a pure business environment

Answer (score 1):

I've just got a new smart phone, (WinMo 6 Pro) and looking at developing for it. Unfortunately there really seems a lack of clear concise guides/documentation/tutorials/books for native Window Mobile development.

Currently the best resource I've found is MSDN, pity it I find it so painful to trawl through.

I can now see why Palm had such an active Dev community, good references, some free tools and simple code/APIs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends - do you intend to build software with the Compact Framework or using Embedded C++ (native applications)?

There doesn't seem to be much in the way of online resources for writing unmanaged applications, but there is a bit of content on Compact Framework development.

The first decent guidance I can recall was from 2006, from the Patterns and Practices team - the Mobile Client Software Factory.  I haven't used it myself (all my mobile app work was done in Visual Studio without the use of additional software) but I know some folks who used it successfully.

It seems Patterns and Practices moved their Smart Client Guidance to codeplex [here](http://www.codeplex.com/smartclient) where they have updated the Mobile Client Software Factory to an [April 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3BE112CC-B2C1-4215-9330-9C8CF9BCC6FA&displaylang=en) release, supporting Visual Studio 2008.

Of course there's the Windows Mobile 6 SDK.. I think the latest SDK is available [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B).